# Android: sending SMS through intent with body and returning back.

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send a SMS through an intent, I want to add a body to the message. After user press `send` I want to return to the app. I've added extra as `sms_body` and `exit_on_sent`. But when I use them both the SMS appears without the body. If i don't use the `exit_on_sent` extra everything works fine.

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
    sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Why you not use startActivityForResult?

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh it doesn't work, it doesn't return to the previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

```
startActivityForResult(sendIntent, SOME_REQUEST_CODE)
```

but in my experience it doesn't works most of the time.
I would recommend instead using SmsManager.

```
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
if(smsMgr != null){
  PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
      getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0,
      new Intent(MY_ACTION_INTENT_SENT), 0);
  smsMgr.sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, sentIntent, null);
}
```

Depending on your application you can do the rest of processing when MY_ACTION_INTENT is sent (indicating the message has actually been sent) or right after sendTextMessage(...) returns.

From API Level 19 there are some interesting features you may found useful http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using the SmsManager I'll have to add permission, and I don't want to do this.