# Android SMS intent exit_on_sent removes message body

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I realize this concern has been expressed before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180060/how-to-return-back-to-intent-after-sending-sms-using-native-sms-composer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786046/android-sending-sms-through-intent-with-body-and-returning-back), but it has never been addressed in the responses (and to be honest has not been the main focus of the question).

I am NOT asking how to return back after using an SMS intent in Android. I am asking how to enable `exit_on_sent` without the side-effect of wiping `sms_body`.

This is my code:

```
Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
msg.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:01234567899"));
msg.putExtra("sms_body", "\n\nSent from my very own App!");
//msg.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
startActivity(msg);
```

It currently works with the message body I supply with `msg.putExtra()`, but does not return back afterwards as the following line is commented out.

But when I uncomment the line which sets `exit_on_sent` to `true`, although the return back functionality now works, the message body is no longer in the SMS app when it opens, nor in the message when viewed after sending.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can I ask if the reason people are not answering this is because it is asked poorly, or in the wrong location or something of that nature?

Comment: hi did you get a solution to this one?

Answer (score 1):

For the `exit_on_sent` to work in conjunction with `sms_body` you will need to use `getDefaultSmsPackage` as per below:

```java
Intent intent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sms body");
        intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(ctx);
        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)
            intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "sms body");
    }
    act.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Using `exit_on_sent` does not work on Android 12. Not sure if it's because of a change in Android or what